# Remove property from mongoose document instance

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I need to remove a property from a mongoose document instance. I've found a lot of questions that show how to remove it from the database, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I need to pull the document down including a field to check security access, I then want to strip that field so that it doesn't get disclosed if downstream code decides to call `toObject()` and send the object back to the client.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

I needed to remove password property from the document instance but I didn't find anything in the API documentation. Here is what I did:

```
doc.set('password', null); // doc.password is null
```

Then I found you can also do this:

```
delete doc._doc.password // doc.password is undefined
```

Comment: I came up with the `delete doc._doc.password` as well. The only caveat is that this also breaks saving the document, which is functionality I need. I'm currently just ignoring this until I have time to find a better solution.

Comment: It breaks saving because your schema expects property as a string and get undefined. Try updating instead of saving.

Comment: The delete method does not work. When you call `doc.save()` it doesn't remove the field from the database. You need to do- `doc.set('password', undefined);`   **Edit**: I think this is actually what the OP wants-- he wants downstream holders of `doc` not to be able to see `password` field, but doesn't sound like he wants the field to actually be removed from the database

Answer (score 8):

Since version 2.4 you can do:

```
doc.field = undefined;
await doc.save();
```

This will essentially `$unset` the field

Comment: This works for save new document, but for update how can i do this?

Comment: This doesn't work to set _id as undefined.

Comment: I assume because the _id is a special property, so no, possibly that won't work. I recommend instead creating a copy of the document using `toObject()` and manipulating that. This is what we use if we want to clone an object, which from what it sounds like you may be trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `set` function with a value of `null` will simply assign the value, not remove it. Best to first convert the document using `toObject()` (so that it is becomes a plain Object), make the changes and revive it back to a model document:

```
let tempDoc = doc.toObject();
delete tempDoc.password;
doc = new this(tempDoc);
```